# A problem with running my python script on a Linux VPS

Tags: bots, telegram

I'm trying to deploy my telegram bot on a linux VPS. I've uploaded the python script to the VPS, but if I run it through `python3 bot_name` command nothing seems to happen because when put in `ps aux` command my bot doesn't show in the processes list. I used systemctl to ensure that the bot works 24/7, but when I type in `systemctl status bot_name` it says the following: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7arPw.png)

So it seems to me that it constantly crashes and then restarts immediately but no error message shows up when I run the script. What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Are you able to produce any logs or ascertain that it can be run on the server?

Comment: I am not sure whether it can be run on the server and I know nothing about logs. I'm a beginner in all of this unfortunately